# How can I do type-guarding for the same object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, frontend, typeguards

For example, I have such a code:

```
interface Subscriber {
  reviewData: string | string[]
  hasArray: boolean;
}

const reviews = ["Good", "Not bad"];

const subscriber: Subscriber = {
  reviewData: reviews,
  hasArray: Array.isArray(reviews)
}

if (subscriber.hasArray) {
  subscriber.reviewData.forEach(console.log);
} else {
  console.log(subscriber.reviewData);
}
```

Of course, TypeScript will complain at `subscriber.reviewData.forEach(console.log);` saying that it can't define whether it's an array or just a string because there's not enough type guarding in the condition `subscriber.hasArray`.

I don't want to always write `Array.isArray(subscriber.reviewData)` because I'm gonna use this logic in many other places.

I've heard of `is` but that's not really the case in my scenario because using `is` implies you have to have a function and pass some argument into it.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Your use case seems to be that `Subscriber` should really be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead of an interface.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7K6DN).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I (or someone) can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see how any of this has to do with "frontend"

Comment: @jcalz that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `hasArray` as a way to determine if `reviewData` is a `string[]` or a `string`, then you really want `Subscriber` to be a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead of an interface.  Your interface would allow `{reviewData: "", hasArray: true}`, and so the compiler cannot discount the possibility.  With a discriminated union you can have a *discriminant property* that you check in order to narrow the type of the whole object:

```
type Subscriber = {
    reviewData: string[]
    hasArray: true;
} | {
    reviewData: string
    hasArray: false;
}
```

In this case `hasArray` is the discriminant property of a boolean [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `true` or `false`.

Then, given a `Subscriber`:

```
const subscriber: Subscriber = Math.random() < 0.5 ?
    { reviewData: "Good", hasArray: false } :
    { reviewData: ["Who", "Cares"], hasArray: true };
```

We can check it the way you want without compiler error:

```
if (subscriber.hasArray) {
    subscriber.reviewData.forEach(console.log);
} else {
    console.log(subscriber.reviewData.toUpperCase());
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwM4GMBOBLBE1QLxQDeAUFGVGhAG4YQDuAIgIbBMBcUSwmAdgOYBtALqlyACyZIAgmjRMQHbnAgBuYgF8oAHyKiylGvWasOXXnz1QJ02fI4AzJgBskqjcWIoA9jy4VqtHRI+FACAEQA4l5eACZhADRQYQByXsBQCExxQmrEThDpSIiomNhoHPDI6Fg4ISTk-oaMLOyNgUjxltYycgpQPfIAdBg2vQAUBu0AlFCSUErQAPSLUN4AtmAY+bgxXhBIPADk6ZTOGABe0MAS6dcjUHRbTlAxEPYYPBjAEE4g-sBwNA8eZoZTuYhFKqlWoEACyLDEgzkPF2azGMwAPFAAAyDACsUAA-JZCG0jC0OJFonFEt1bH1HC5oJo2CSyc0TKEwgB1MReBJJADCTEoSDCQlpkgGfQWUHUuWIGHsUDGkJKNTQgzpvRm9XIauqZSRAXJrEG9i8aAAokwUGIxt5fF58oMnF4+FM1Jofq5dA1HUhnRBXe7VcVDThjU1jExBsAvABVMCQNDC1zoz0aIA)